# what's the problem with this error please answer

Tags: compiler-errors

Error code on image:/storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/620/app/src/main/res/layout/menu_utama_download.xml:67: error: resource drawable/link (aka com.rehandev.TikTokDownloader:drawable/link) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.

Please how to solve it? I made an application in sketchware

Can you guys help me with this error